# convert None to empty string and flatten list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to convert a list of lists to a list of strings but also convert all None values to an empty string.

```
[','.join(x) for x in ["" if value is None else value for value in [func.get(x) for x in MY_CONST]]]
```

`MY_CONST = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`

`func` returns an output that looks like this: `{'a': ['v1'], 'b': ['v2'], 'c': ['v31', 'v32'], 'd': ['v4']}`

I have this 3 stage list comprehension above to check if a value in `MY_CONST` does not exist as a key in `func`, None is inserted, convert None to empty string, then flatten the list.

```
[['v1'], ['v2'], ['v31', 'v32'], ['v4'], None]
[['v1'], ['v2'], ['v31', 'v32'], ['v4'], '']
['v1', 'v2', 'v31,v32', 'v4', '']
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this without having to do it the way I'm currently doing it?

Comment: How about `func.get(x, [''])`?

Comment: Following the above would leave you with: `[", ".join(func.get(x, [''])) for x in MY_CONST]` which seems like a nice improvement.

Comment: @barmar would you give a proper answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```py
MY_CONST = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
funcOP = {'a': ['v1'], 'b': ['v2'], 'c': ['v31', 'v32'], 'd': ['v4']}
result = [','.join(funcOP.get(key, [''])) for key in MY_CONST]
```

`dict.get` accepts an optional default argument, and will return this value if the key is not found in the dictionary

**OUTPUT**

```py
Out[91]: ['v1', 'v2', 'v31,v32', 'v4', '']
```

**PS**: It doesn't encounter for the keys that are in `funcOP` but not in `MY_CONST` as you have mentioned nothing about it in the problem description.